# Playing Video Streaming direct from FTP

Tags: java, html, ftp

i'm working with FTP and Java so i need reproduce some videos:

I have a lot of videos in a FTP server and i should reproduce this videos in a HTTP (Apache Tomcat) WebServer. I shouldn't download this video, i would like to play direct from FTP.

Today i'm using HTML5 video tag, but i download the video to a TEMP folder and after reproduce in Browser, but this proccess is very slow.

```
 <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content"><h:form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <video width="600" controls="controls">
                            <source src="#{acervoVideoListMB.videoView}" type="video/mp4"/>
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:form></section>
            <!-- /.content -->
```

Comment: You should try to use a different protocol. I don't think ftp was designed to do something like this. Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media

Comment: Thanks for your reply.